# Local redundancy - Product Quantization and global redundancy - Residual Quantization connection

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, compression

I am currently reading [Compressing Deep Convolutional Networks using Vector Quantization](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6115v1.pdf) paper. The paper states in section 3.2.5 that **Product Quantization** explores some **local redundancy** and **Residual Quantization** explores **global redundancy** structure between weight vectors.

My general question is **what is the connection between product quantization and local redundancy, and between residual quantization and global redundancy?**

To make the answer clearer for me, I have more detail questions behind that general question:

1. What do local redundancy and global redundancy mean? I tried to search, and found [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundant_proof), but I don't understand it. Can someone explain it to me in an easy and intuitive way?
2. I am still not fully understand the product quantization technique in this paper. This is my current understanding:

   - The weight matrix size is *mxn*. And the *n* is divided by *s* number of partition. For example, *n = 8* ; *s = 2*. So it partition to 4.
   - The codebook (for saving centroid) for each partition is a *kx(n/s)* matrix. *k* is number of codebook. *n/s* is column size of each partition. So, the 1 centroid has *n/s* member? I don't understand this. I always think that 1 centroid is 1 number / value.

3. I know how to count the residual quantization. But, I don't understand what it does intuitively, i.e., what can make the quantization result become similar with original; and what does the quantization of residual do?

I prefer as easy an explanation as possible (with words and intuitively). Some mathematics is okay to support the explanation if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

if we think of a neuron $w$ as a matrix

K-Means is doing element-wise clustering,
Product Quantization is doing submatrix-wise clustering for submatrices of the same index ,
Residual Quantization is doing matrix-wise clustering recursively.

that's why the author states that KM maintains no structure, PQ maintains local structure and RQ maintains global structure.

hope that helps with your questions.